# Can't run rosbag2-py on imx8

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am compiling ROS2 galactic through Yocto for an imx8qm.  The only thing that doesn't work is rosbag2-py.
When I run ros2 bag on the device, I get the error:
Failed to load entry point 'play' : No module named 'rosbag2_py._reader'.
In the /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rosbag2-py folder, all of the files end in 'cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'.
I would expect them to be 'cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so', so it looks like Yocto isn't cross-compiling them.
How do I change the yocto recipe so that the python libraries are cross-compiled?

Update:  file I run the 'file' command on the librarys, I can see that the files are being built for ARM aarch64, even though they are named '..x86_64..'.  The problem seems to be that ros2 bag isn't finding them properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414938/can%27t-run-rosbag2-py-on-imx8/) by [eburley](https://answers.ros.org/users/147401/eburley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the so files were not being named correctly.  I added a bbappend file with the following fix:

do_install:append() {
install -d ${D}${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR}
for f in $(find ${D}${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR} -name "*x86_64*"); do
    mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/x86_64/aarch64/')
done
}

This renames all of the *.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so files to *.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.  Now ros2 bag finds the modules correctly.

---

Originally posted by [eburley](https://answers.ros.org/users/147401/eburley/) with karma: 16 on 2023-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0